# How to get the names from multiple lists at once?

Tags: r

I have two listing `plot_overall_hema` and `plot_overall_chem`. I would like to get get all  names from each list to a df with name `outputs`. How can I achieve this goal?

I can use codes like `names(plot_overall_hema)` to get the names from each list. Is it a more convenient way to get all names from multiple listing? for example, if I have more than 2 lists, like 10 list?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through and get names:

```
# example lists
plot_overall_chem <- list(one = 1, two = 2)
plot_overall_hema <- list(three = 3, four = 4)


unlist(lapply(ls(pattern = "plot_"), function(i) names(get(i))))
# [1] "one"   "two"   "three" "four
```

To keep the list names we can stack:

```
stack(sapply(ls(pattern = "plot_"), function(i) names(get(i)), simplify = FALSE))
#   values               ind
# 1    one plot_overall_chem
# 2    two plot_overall_chem
# 3  three plot_overall_hema
# 4   four plot_overall_hema
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Is it possible to add list name as df.lstname, and names from each list as df.output? How can I loop through and get such dataset?

Comment: @Stataq see edit, you can change the column names as per your need, "values" and "ind" are default names from stack.